# SAXParseException when print the pdf from xslt and xml

Tags: java, xml, pdf, xslt

> I am trying to generate pdf from xml and xslt.

```
[Fatal Error] :89:14: Invalid byte 1 of 1-byte UTF-8 sequence.
file:////; Line #89; Column #14; org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:////; lineNumber: 89; columnNumber: 14; Invalid byte 1 of 1-byte UTF-8 sequence.
```

> severe:XSLT Transformation failed null
>
> JBAS014134: EJB Invocation failed on component PDFGenerationBean for
>   method public abstract java.util.List
>   au.com.copl.dbaccesslayer.session.PDFGenerationRemote.getPDFs(java.util.List,java.util.List,java.lang.Integer,java.lang.Integer)
>   throws java.lang.Exception: javax.ejb.EJBException:
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Would you be so kind and show `lineNumber: 89; columnNumber: 14`?

Comment: <table-row  border=".5pt solid black" border-bottom="0pt solid black"  >

Comment: Seems to be an encoding issue (I'm guessing, because we do not see any code). What happens if you delete this line and type it again, by hand, making sure that the editor you've opened the code with is set to UTF-8?

Comment: I don't see how "border" can contain anything that's not proper UTF-8. Is this from the XML or XSLT file? What is line 89 in the other file? What file is "////"?

Comment: @laune: it may still be something like a fixed space. Using a good code editor, do a GREP search for `[^[:ascii:]]`.

Comment: @Jongware Column 14 would be right in the middle of "border". Of course, leading spaces might throw my naive count way off. OP needs to provide more info, and in an exact way.

Comment: Part 1 – contains information about us and the services we can provide to you; and. 
above line is 89

Comment: thanks for helping me to tracing the problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Line 89 is

> Part 1 – contains information about us and the services we can provide
>   to you; and.

```
Actually - sign creating the problem here. Now I have removed from this line. And pdf generated successfully.
```

now changed with this line

> Part 1 contains information about us and the services we can provide
>   to you; and.

Comment: Deleting that one character is a temporary one-time fix. Alternatives: 1. Your XML contains characters in some encoding *other than UTF8* even though it was stated somewhere that was its encoding (possibly by default). Change to, or add the correct encoding. 2. Convert the characters to proper UTF8. 3. Use entity (`&ndash;`) or literal (`&#x2013;`) notation instead, for all not-ASCII characters.